# What happens if a HDD of my RAID1 setup fails?

Tags: server, hard-drive, raid

I have the following setup:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        37G  1.1G   34G   4% /
udev            1.6G  4.0K  1.6G   1% /dev
tmpfs           651M  348K  651M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/shm
/dev/md0        294G  191M  279G   1% /home
```

`/dev/md0` are two HDDs set as (software) RAID1.

What happens if one of these two HDDs fails? Would `/dev/md0` still be accessible and working? If so, how do I know if one RAID1 device fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your configuration, RAID 1 allows you to loose 1 physical drive.

If your RAID is available at `dev/md0` you'll be able to access your data if one drive is faulty

If you want to have detail informations about your RAID, you can use the following command :

```
sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
```

And the result :

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 00.90.01
  Creation Time : Wed Aug 31 09:38:34 2005
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 76670144 (73.12 GiB 78.51 GB)
    Device Size : 76670144 (73.12 GiB 78.51 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Sep  9 10:50:48 2005
          State : active
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 48b74990:15f454d9:93947193:76d9ea46
         Events : 0.60924

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       19        0      active sync   /dev/sdb3
       1       8        3        1      active sync   /dev/sda3
```

How do you build your RAID 1 ? OK

If you want to know the state of your RAID & Drive :

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Could be usefull

If you want to receive mail from the mdam daemon, you should check in the manual, I think (because I don't use it, but I 've search informations for you :p)

```
mdadm --monitor --mail=myemail@example.com /dev/md0 &
```

If a failure occure you'll receive a mail. I think I'll build a VM for working with HD HA.

Comment: I have set up the RAID during my the partitioning step of my Ubuntu Server (12.04) installation. My output of `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` is pretty similar to yours. Do you know if there is anyway to list just the `Failed Devices`? Doing so would be really easy to set up a script and a cron job to notify me. I've seen that mdadm is pretty powerful and flexible, but since my need is really simple I prefer doing this way instead of diving deep into it.