# Ubuntu Server 18.04 software RAID 1 definition

Tags: server, raid

I am unable to find the exact specifications of how the RAID 1 logic is executed in Ubuntu Server 18.04.  More precisely, I am interested in setting up a RAID 1 software mirroring using two identical SSD drives, and  would like to know how does the system behave when one of the drives goes bad and shuts down. Does the system shut down as well? If I unplug the bad drive and leave the second one does the second boot the same way the first one does? (eg. does it have the bootloader as well)

Comment: Have you looked at the manual pages for raid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install GRUB on a RAID system installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43036/how-do-i-install-grub-on-a-raid-system-installation)

Comment: Multiple questions asked, but the answers are here: https://askubuntu.com/a/189904/12864 and here: https://askubuntu.com/q/287249/12864